# How to use regexp_replace() with GROUP BY clause in presto query

Tags: sql, postgresql, presto

I am trying to retrieve records based on a custom field "*ci_ku*". For the same values of "*ci_ku*" we will be having multiple "*l1m_visits*", and I want to retrieve the minimum value of "*l1mvisits*" for each "*ci_ku*".

**Sample Data**:

| ku | ci_ku | l1m_visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234-5678-HIJK | 1234-HIJK | A |
| 1234-9012-HIJK | 1234-HIJK | B |

**Expected Output**:

| ku | ci_ku | l1m_visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234-5678-HIJK | 1234-HIJK | A |

Have tried the query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_REPLACE(ku, CONCAT('-',CAST(v_nbr AS varchar)), '') AS ci_ku,
                ku,
                MIN(l1m_visits),
                last_refresh_date 
FROM db.schema.table 
GROUP BY ci_ku;
```

and facing the following error:

> line 1:194: Column 'ci_ku' cannot be resolved

Comment: Presto or Postgres?

Comment: Why is `ci_ku` in your sample data when it doesn't exists yet, and why is `v_nbr` not in your sample data...

Comment: Please add the relevant sample data, current one can not be used for the query due to missing fields (`last_refresh_date`, `v_nbr`) (i.e. add a [mre]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is fired because the field "*ci_ku*" is not yet generated when the `GROUP BY` clause is evaluated. Further there are some more issues in your query:

- not all non-aggregated rows are found within the `GROUP BY` clause ("*ku*" and "*last_refresh_date*" should be included)
- the `DISTINCT` keyword will remove duplicate rows, though there are none after your `SELECT` statement.

Instead of using aggregation, the `ROW_NUMBER` window function may get your result faster. It will generate an incremental number for each of your "*ci_ku*" values (`PARTITION BY ci_ku`) and ordered by "*l1m_visits*" (`ORDER BY ci_ku`), such that your row number equal to 1 will represent the lowest "*l1m_visits*" for each "*ci_ku*".

```
WITH tab_with_ci_ku AS (
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(ku, CONCAT('-',CAST(v_nbr AS varchar)), '') AS ci_ku,
           ku,
           l1m_visits,
           last_refresh_date
    FROM db.schema.table 
), ranked_visits AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ci_ku ORDER BY l1m_visits) AS rn
    FROM tab_with_ci_ku
)
SELECT ku,
       ci_ku,
       l1m_visits
FROM ranked_visits
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you're using PostgreSQL, you can also use the [`FETCH n ROWS WITH TIES`](https://FETCH%20FIRST%20n%20ROWS%20WITH%20TIES) clause that retrieves the first row for each tied row number (it will pick the each row number = 1):

```
WITH tab_with_ci_ku AS (
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(ku, CONCAT('-',CAST(v_nbr AS varchar)), '') AS ci_ku,
           ku,
           l1m_visits,
           last_refresh_date
    FROM db.schema.table 
)
SELECT ku,
       ci_ku,
       l1m_visits
FROM ranked_visits
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ci_ku ORDER BY l1m_visits)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

Comment: Only you can tell me if this was helpful to your case. Does this query work for your db?

Comment: Hi @lemon thankyou verymuch for your response, above query worked!!.

Comment: Hi @lemon , I want to get the ci_ku by removing the string between 1st and 2nd underscore(-) in ku, how to write a query to get the ci_ku , can refer the question posted here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73826720/query-to-remove-everything-between-1st-and-2nd-underscore-for-string-in-column-u