# query to remove everything between 1st and 2nd hypen for string in column

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, presto

I am trying to retrieve records based on a custom field "*ci_ku*". For the same values of "*ci_ku*" we will be having multiple "*l1m_visits*", and I want to retrieve the minimum value of "*l1mvisits*" for each "*ci_ku*". and i want to get the **ci_ku** by removing the string between 1st and 2nd underscore(-) in **ku**, how to write a query to get the ci_ku here

**Sample Data**:

| ku | item | l1m_visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234-5678-HIJK | 1234 | A |
| 1234-9012-HIJK | 1234 | B |
| 56457-12456-DF-GH-TC | 56457 | D |

**Expected Output**:

| ku | ci_ku | l1m_visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234-5678-HIJK | 1234-HIJK | A |
| 56457-12456-DF-GH-TC | 56457-DF-GH-TC | D |

Have tried the query below:

```
WITH tab_with_ci_ku AS (
   select split(ku, '-', 3)ivm_arr,

           l1m_visits,
           last_refresh_date
    FROM db.scema.table
), ranked_visits AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(ivm_arr[2],item) as ci_sku ORDER BY l1m_visits) AS rn
    FROM tab_with_ci_ku
)
SELECT sku,ci_ku
FROM ranked_visits
WHERE rn = 1
```

and facing the following error:

```
 mismatched input 'ci_ku'. Expecting: 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CALL', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DEALLOCATE', 'DELETE', 'DENY', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DROP', 'EXECUTE', 'EXPLAIN', 'GRANT', 'INSERT', 'MERGE', 'PREPARE', 'REFRESH', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'TRUNCATE', 'UPDATE', 'USE', <query>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regex replacement to handle the `ci_ku` requirement.  Note that this replacement should happen *first*, as the call to `ROW_NUMBER` depends on it.

```sql
WITH tab_with_ci_ku AS (
    SELECT *, REGEXP_REPLACE(ku, '([^-]+)-[^-]+-(.*)', '$1-$2') AS ci_ku
    FROM db.schema.table
),
ranked_visits AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ci_ku ORDER BY l1m_visits) AS rn
    FROM tab_with_ci_ku
)

SELECT ku, ci_ku, l1m_visits
FROM ranked_visits
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

- `([^-]+)` match and capture in `$1` the first term
- `-` match a literal hyphen
- `[^-]+` match the second term (to be excluded in the replacement)
- `-` match a literal hyphen
- `(.*)` match and capture in `$2` the remainder of the SKU

Then we replace with `$1-$2` to effectively splice out the second term.

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen, thankyou very much for your response, it is working fine, could you please explain how this regex works :'([^-]+)-[^-]+-(.*)', '$1-$2'

Comment: Please check the updated answer above.

Comment: Thankyou @Tim Biegeleisen, what is the reason behind using [^-] for first term and (.*) for 2nd term

Comment: @AmulyaM Well the final `(.*)` basically says to just capture everything remaining.  At this point, we have already spliced out the second term.

Comment: okay @Tim Biegeleisen, thanks for your quick response